# Batch file opening Excel file and Macro

Tags: excel, batch-file, vba

I want to create a batch file which when I run this file, an excel file should open with some columns in it.

Say if I click on batch file, excel file with columns name, project, ID should also get included in excel file.

Also with this a macro should be open.

Please help. I dont have any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to automate excel with pure batch.

Why not:

- Create an "template" excel file with the default columns and macro included
- Have a batch file copy this template (`copy template.xslx newfile.xslx`) file and open it (`` `Start newfile.xslx ``).

For the new file, you'd either have to generate a random or timestamp-based name or have the user enter the name before making a copy.